# Group query results after they have already been grouped (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ok so basically what i'm trying to do is return a set of results grouped twice from the same query from the same table.

I have three columns: 'type', 'amount' and 'date'.

What I need to do is sum the entire table of amounts, then group them by date and then group them again by type: I want the sum of the amounts for each date, grouped by type.

My query is as follows:

```
$this->db->select("*, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m') as date_formatted", FALSE)->select_sum('total')->from('accounts')->group_by('date');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Any help is most appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure SQL it would look like:

```
SELECT date, type, SUM(amount) as TOTAL
FROM accounts
GROUP BY date, type;
```

I guess rewriting it in PHP might be close :)